# $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i \rightarrow \int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: probability

---

**PROBLEM**

Let $X_1,Y_1,X_2,Y_2,...$ be a sequence of independent random variables, all of which distributed uniformly on $[0,1]$. Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a continuous function. Define $Z_i = 1_{f(X_i)>Y_i}$.

$a)$ Show that almost surely $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i \rightarrow \int_0^1f(x)dx$

$b)$ Show that $E(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i - \int_0^1f(x)dx)^2 \leq \frac{1}{4n}$

---

I don't know how to attack this problem, I hope that someone could help me..

Comment: Is $F$ supposed to be $f$ in the definition of $Z_i$? And $y_i$ supposed to be $Y_i$ I assume?

Comment: @Tom Yes, that's true, will edit right now, thank you

Comment: Do you know the strong law of large numbers (at least for Bernoulli trials) and have you tried to compute $E(Z_i) = P(Z_i = 1)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

a) Note that $Z_i$ are i.i.d. random variable with mean $\mu = E[Z_i]$. Therefore the LLN tells you that 
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^N Z_i \to \mu
$$
almost surely. 
Note also:
$$
E[Z_i] = \iint_{\{(x,y):f(x)>y\}} \rho_{X_i,Y_i}(x,y) \,dx\,dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^{f(x)} \,dy\,dx
$$
where I used $\rho_{X_i,Y_i}(x,y)$ as the joint density of $(X_i, Y_i)$.

b)
$$
E\big[\big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_1^n Z_i - \mu \big)^2\big] = \frac{1}{n^2}E\big[\big(\sum_{1}^n \{Z_i - \mu\}\big)^2 \big] $$

Comment: Thank you, I see what you are doing, how can I show that $\mu = \int_0^1f(x)dx$?

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal I updated the solution to reflect your comment question.

Comment: Thank you again, can you please explain how you come from the first double integral to the second?

Comment: Notice that $$\rho_{X,Y} = \begin{cases} 1 & 0<x<1, 0<y<1 \\0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ Therefore the region you are integrating over is $$\{ 0 < x < 1 \} \cap \{0 < y < 1\} \cap \{y < f(x)\}$$ Putting this together, you find that the region you are integrating over is $\{ 0 < x < 1, ~0 < y < f(x)\}$ which are the bounds in the second.